# Remove found entry from HashMap without cloning the key

Tags: rust

I am finding a certain entry in a `HashMap` (in this case it's the one that's "least used"). I now want to remove that entry from the map. Since the key was obtained from the `HashMap` itself (and thus is a reference), how can I now use it to remove the entry without cloning the key.

Here is a small, runnable example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut usage = HashMap::<String, usize>::new();
    
    usage.insert("entry one".to_owned(), 5);
    usage.insert("entry two".to_owned(), 1);
    
    let mut least_used: Option<(&String, &usize)> = None;
    for curr in usage.iter() {
        if let Some(prev) = least_used {
            if curr.1 < prev.1 {
                least_used = Some(curr);
            }
        } else {
            least_used = Some(curr);
        }
    }
    
    println!("{:?}", least_used);
    
    usage.remove(least_used.unwrap().0);
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=308e9b5b81e480c405c894ead381eef8)

The error I'm getting is:

```
cannot borrow `usage` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

Comment: Nitpick: You're reinventing [`Iterator::min_by_key()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.min_by_key).

Comment: There sure are possibilities, the question is whether there is an efficient one. You could always move all entries in a vector, sort the vector by the least_used, cut the last element off, and then convert it back to a HashMap. The problem is more general: If you have a `remove(x)` function, then `x` is either a referenc or a value. Value cannot be, because the value is still inside the hashmap, and reference cannot be implemented in a sound way because the act of `remove`ing it invalidates the reference and therefore leaves it dangling.

Comment: I think cloning the key really is the best way.